# find the nth root using binary search algorithm using C

Tags: c

```
double x;
size_t n;
double precision;

double high = x < 1.0 ? 1.0 : x;
double min = 0.0;
double unknown = //idk??

double eps = 1e-6; 

double multiply(double number, int n) {
    double ans = 1.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        ans = ans * number;
    }
    return ans;
}

while (precision < error) {
    while ((high - min) > eps) {
        double old = (min + high) / 2.0; 
        if(multiply(old, n) < unknown) {
            min = old; 
        } else {
            high = old; 
        }
    }
}

printf("%f", unknown);
```

Trying to find the nth root using binary search algorithm. Can someone spot any logic errors that is keeping my code from working? Appreciated.

Comment: can we see the full code please, this isnt even close to compiling

Comment: @pm100 please consider this as a pseudocode. I am not able to upload the full. code as it is not letting me to.

Comment: I mean its impossible to say what the issue is, in the real code do you initalize precision? What number are you trying to find the root of? The code never exits because precision is never updated. I assume precision is supposed to be the difference between n and the result of 'multiply' (which should be called 'power')

Comment: what is error supposed to be, its not even defeined

Comment: your code is quite close to working, buts so wrong its hard to know what to say. But anyway, you dont need precision, error of the outer while loop. Your code then finds sqrt of 43= 6.5574 in 26 iterations

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code cleaned up. The outer loop isn't needed. It doesn't work with negative numbers; I did not drill into why. I did not change your 'multiply' function so its not here

```
int main() {

    double x = 42; // number we want the root of
    size_t n = 2;  // the root we want

    // squeeze boundaries
    double high = x < 1.0 ? 1.0 : x;
    double min = 0.0;
    double eps = 1e-6; // how tight we want to squeeze the answer

    int iterations = 0; // count of iterations for interest
    double guess = 0;   // our current guess at the root

    while ((high - min) > eps) {
        iterations++;
        guess = (min + high) / 2.0;
        double guessPow = multiply(guess, n);
        if (guessPow < x) {
            min = guess;
        }
        else {
            high = guess;
        }
    }
    printf("%f %d %f", x, iterations, guess);

}
```

the core logic is still yours, so you should fix it so that cube root of -8 comes out as -2.

Comment: If the number is < 0 (and odd), just take the root of its abs value, and negate the result :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double nth_root(double d, int n) {
    double x = d; // guess greater than result
    for (; x - .001 > (x -= (pow(x, n) - d) / (n * pow(x, n - 1))););
    return x;
}

// using Newton's method
int main(void) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        double n = 625;
        double a = pow(n, 1. / i); // C answer
        double b = nth_root(n, i); // your answer
        printf("nth_root(%g, %d) = %-9g (found %-9g, diff is %.15f)\n", n, i, a, b, b - a);
    }
}
```

If you need a pow function :

```c
double my_pow(double n, unsigned long long int power) {
    if (power) {
        double tmp = 1;
        for (; power > 1; n *= n)
            if (power & 1) {
                tmp *= n;
                power = (power - 1) >> 1;
            } else
                power >>= 1;
        n *= tmp;
    } else
        n = 1;
    return n;
}
```